# "Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'. ',"

Tags: flutter

Compiler message:
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4/lib/svg.dart:158:18: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
        context: 'picture failed to precache',
                 ^
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:335:20: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
          context: 'while resolving a picture',
                   ^
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:337:33: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
          informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
                                ^
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:432:31: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
        informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
                              ^
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:495:31: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
        informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
                              ^
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:559:31: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
        informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
                              ^
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:256:16: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
      context: context,
               ^
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:301:18: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
        context: 'resolving a single-frame picture stream',
                 ^
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4/lib/src/svg/parser_state.dart:399:35: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
            informationCollector: (StringBuffer buff) {
                                  ^
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4/lib/src/svg/parser_state.dart:408:22: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
            context: 'in _Element.clipPath',
                     ^
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4/lib/src/svg/parser_state.dart:798:31: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
        informationCollector: (StringBuffer buff) {
                              ^
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4/lib/src/svg/parser_state.dart:809:18: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
        context: 'in parseSvgElement',
                 ^
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_advanced_networkimage-0.4.15/lib/src/flutter_advanced_networkimage.dart:149:29: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
      informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
                            ^
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_advanced_networkimage-0.4.15/lib/src/flutter_advanced_networksvg.dart:106:29: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
      informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
                            ^
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4/lib/src/utilities/errors.dart:8:32: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
      context: 'in $methodName',
                               ^
file:///home/cepl/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4/lib/src/utilities/errors.dart:10:29: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///home/cepl/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
      informationCollector: (StringBuffer buff) {
                            ^
Compiler failed on /home/cepl/Divum-Ajit/Flutter/weupdateyou-consumer-flutter/lib/main.dart
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 4):

For me it was fixed upgrading the package `cached_network_image` to the version `0.8.0`.

Edit the file pubspec.yaml from your Flutter project and upgrade to the latest version.

> cached_network_image: ^0.8.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your svg library to the latest version.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg#-installing-tab-

You can found their discussion about that issue 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31962

Comment: i haven't used flutter_svg in my yaml file. but still i m getting this error. recently i have upgraded flutter version to Channel beta, v1.6.3

Answer (score 0):

i have experienced the same problem after upgrading to flutter 1.7 it gave the same error with many packages the solution is to upgrade your packages in pubspec.yaml